# How many ways to choose 5 points from a circle

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Let there be 15 equidistant points, each pair of which is 1-unit distant from one another, on a circle with a 15-unit circumference. How many ways are there to choose 5 points that no two of them are 3 or 5-unit distance away?\

Let $B_3$ be the set of choices such that at least a pair of points are 3 distance away. Define $B_5$ similarly. Then, what we want is $|X\setminus (B_3 \cup B_5)|$, where $X$ is the set of all choices. Since our choice of points divides circle into 5 segments of a positive integer length it is the same as counting the solutions to the equation
$$
a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4+ a_5 = 15
$$
so $|X| = {14\choose 4}$. Similarly, $B_3$ is the same as choosing one of those $5$ variables and assigning it $3$ and solving the equation for the remaining $4$ variables, and we can say something similar for $B_5$ as well.
$$
|B_3| = 5*{12\choose 3}, |B_5| = 5*{10\choose 3}
$$
Again, $|B_3\cap B_5| = {7\choose 2} * {5\choose 2}$. Finally the answer seems to be
$$
{14\choose 4} - 5*{12\choose 3}- 5*{10\choose 3} + {7\choose 2} * {5\choose 2}.
$$

But, I feel somewhat uneasy about this solution. Is it really correct?

Comment: Your answer is less than zero, so it cannot be correct.

Comment: "no two of them are 3 or 5-unit distance away" won't happen as they form a pair which by assumption is "1-unit distant from one another"?

Comment: I suspect the only ways to do so is picking cyclic permutations of $ \{ 1, 2, 3, 9, 10 \}$.

Comment: @CalvinLin $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$ is another, and there is no third.

Comment: Is there a general way to solve this kind of problem on a circle of length $pq$ such that no two points are $p$ or $q$ distance away where $(p, q) =1$. Say we choose $p$ points from the circle.